# Regex Matching a string

Tags: c++, regex, string, dfa, nfa

I currently am writing a regex to match strings such as this:

```
( expr ) | id | num
term * factor | factor
expr
```

I want the regex to match each occurence of set of characters between each ' | ', but also match solo expressions such as:

```
expr
```

I currently have this, but I am doing my negative lookahead wrong and I am not really sure how to proceed.

```
((.*) \|) (.*)$
```

P.s. I am not really fond of using .* in this situation, but I cannot think of another way to match, because the characters between ' | 's can be word characters, digits, or anything in between.

EDIT:

I would like the output matches to look like this:

Regex ran on line 1, output:

```
3 matches - ( expor ), id, num
```

Regex ran on line 2:

```
2 matches - term * factor, factor
```

Regex ran on line 3:

```
1 match - expr
```

Comment: You aren't doing any negative lookaheads...also you don't specify what the output of the second line should be or why `expr` by itself should match.  There's a lot of seemingly arbitrary rules here.  You need to be more concrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be your simple regex:

```
[^|]+
```

-capture one or more characters until you reach "|" (or end of string)

Or alternatively you could use String.split("|");

```
String line = "term * factor | factor";
String[] split = line.split("\\|");
```